# Conditional operator behaviour

Tags: java, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

Can anybody explain the logic behind the output of below code?

```
    if(true||false&&false){
        System.out.println("right to left ");
    }
    if (false && true||true){
        System.out.println("left to right");
    }
```

Comment: && has higher precedence than ||, so the expressions are parenthesized as `(true || (false && false))` and `((false && true) || true)`. You can work it out from there.

Comment: That is correct http://bmanolov.free.fr/javaoperators.php It goes without saying that writing either of these in a real program is asking for trouble; brackets are always good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [this Operator precedence table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), you can see that `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`.

Therefore, the two expressions are evaluated like this:

`true || false && false` == `true || (false && false)` == `true`

`false && true || true`  == `(false && true) || true`  == `true`

Comment: @ Keppil thanks a lot man for explaining it in a very simple way . Very basic thing bt still it made me scratch my head for a while.

Answer (score 1):

`if(true||false&&false)` can be simplified to true so it prints the line.  It can be simplified to true because you have a `true` on the left hand side.  Since there's an or/`||` on the right of it, and things are already true, it means it can short circuit and not evaluate the rest.  You can prove this to yourself by taking the `false&&false`, putting it in its own method, and then printing a line before it returns.  You'll see that it doesn't print. That's because the `(false && false)` is not even evaluated.

`false && true||true` can be simplified to true so it prints the line.  The `false && true` evaluates to false, but since there's an or left over, it evaluates the other side of that.  That turns out to be true.  Since `false||true` == `true`, that evaluates to true.  There is no short circuiting here though.  You can prove this by extracting the `false && true` into its own method and printing something on the first line.  You'll see that it prints:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    if(true|| doSomething()){
        System.out.println("right to left ");
    }
    if (doSomethingElse() ||true){
        System.out.println("left to right");
    }

}

private static boolean doSomething() {
    System.out.println("do something"); //this does NOT print
    return false&&false;
}

private static boolean doSomethingElse() {
    System.out.println("do something else");    //this DOES print
    return false && true;
}
```

Comment: @user2388736 it's as dlev said.  But after you wrap it in parenthesis, it evaluates from left to right.

Comment: I wish I knew why I'm getting up and downvotes like crazy on this.  Someone give a reason for the downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Java gives the different operator precedence to `&&` and `||`. That means your expressions can be written as `true || (false && false)` and `(false && true) || true`. When you see an "or true" in a boolean expression, it's always true. Which is why both strings are printed.

If you want your expressions to be clear, you can always put brackets around the `x && y` parts.

Answer (score 0):

First of all such if cases are eliminated at compile time, as long as the result is constant.

||(or) - addition

&&(and) - multiplication

that's why && has a higher precedence than ||

So by precedence expressions are equal to:

`true + (false * false)` and `(false * true) + true`